# How to retrieve an error message from a php file to another php file?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm new to ajax and this is my first attempt to use it.

What I'm trying to do is create a small system to register an email and password to the database without updating the page and it worked just fine!

However, as you will notice on my 'register.php' file, there is a condition to not allow duplicate emails, as well as PDOException to prevent errors...so, how can I send a message (an alert or whatever) to my index page in case any of them occurs?

This is my .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btnRegister").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'register.php',
            data: { txtEmail: $("#frmEmail").val(), txtPassword: $("#frmPassword").val() }
        }).done(function(){
            $("#frmEmail").val('');
            $("#frmPassword").val('');
            $("#frmEmail").focus();
        });
    });
});
```

My 'register.php' file:

```
<?php

    try
    {
        $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=register', 'root', '');
        $handler -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $email = $_POST['txtEmail'];
        $password = $_POST['txtPassword'];

        $sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?";
        $query = $handler -> prepare($sql);
        $query -> bindValue(1, $email);
        $query -> execute();

        if(($query -> rowCount()) != 0)
            die("Error: the inserted email already exists.");
        else
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, pass) VALUES (?, ?)";
            $query = $handler -> prepare($sql);
            $query -> bindValue(1, $email);
            $query -> bindValue(2, $password);
            $query -> execute();
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Error: " . $ex -> getMessage());
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, your PHP file would return a response indicating the success or failre of the registration.

In your PHP file, instead of `die`ing when there is an error, you should return a json-encoded array containing the error message, for example:

```
if(($query -> rowCount()) != 0)
    echo json_encode(array('error' => "Error: the inserted email already exists."));
    exit;
else
```

Then in your javascript's `done` function, you can check for this message:

```
}).done(function(data){
    if (data.error) {
        alert(data.error); // or do something else
    } else {
        // every thing looks ok, do your thing
    }
});
```

I'd recommend always returning *something* from php, whether it's an error message as above, or simply `json_encode(array('success' => true));`. That way, you can be sure that the request has actually done what is expected, and not returned a blank page for another (bad) reason.

Note: if you have problems getting this to work, you might need to add `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax options (under `type: 'post'`)

Comment: Haha! it's way easier than I thought! thank you, icecub's answer was really helpful too! it's working now, The reason I was using the 'die' function is because I was sending the user to another page, so then I thought "this might be a good opportunity to learn ajax" and I see I'll be learning some JSON as well...

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change all the `die();` to `echo "";` so instead of killing the PHP part, it returns the messages towards your index file. Next just change your jQuery script to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btnRegister").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'register.php',
            data: { txtEmail: $("#frmEmail").val(), txtPassword: $("#frmPassword").val() }
        }).done(function(msg){
            if(msg != ''){
                alert(msg);
            }
            $("#frmEmail").val('');
            $("#frmPassword").val('');
            $("#frmEmail").focus();
        });
    });
});
```